# How to detectd that log4j not is not properly initialized

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I know that when neither log4j.properties nor log4j.xml is found on the classpath, we got a

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (xxx).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

How can I detect that in java so that I could execute some custom code? Example: to print something to my user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to check if any log4j appenders are configured in classpath

```
Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(XXX.class);
Enumeration enum1 = LOGGER.getAllAppenders();

if(!enum1.hasMoreElements())
{
        // Custom print
}
```